# How to create svg file in jsp?

Tags: jsp, svg

I'm trying to create jsp page which will create a svg graphic file. Based on various examples of jsp pages and svgs i come with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<%@ page language="java" contentType="image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8;"    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
response.addHeader(
        "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=blob3" );
%>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="140" width="140" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
  <circle cx="7" cy="7" r="6" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

but it is not working. it allows me to download blob3.svg file, but it is empty file.

Can anyone could give me hint, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Content-Disposition cause the download.

Here is a complete example that is working for many years for me :

```
<%@ page
    import = "com.spectotechnologies.util.XML"
    import = "com.spectotechnologies.website.systems.reports.helper.Report"
    import = "com.spectotechnologies.website.systems.helper.MeasurePoint"
    import = "com.spectotechnologies.website.systems.reports.helper.ReportPeriod"
    import = "com.spectotechnologies.website.systems.reports.helper.ReportField"
    import = "java.sql.Date"
    import = "java.text.NumberFormat"
    import = "java.text.SimpleDateFormat"

    contentType = "image/svg+xml"
%>
<jsp:useBean id="report" scope="request" class="com.spectotechnologies.website.systems.reports.helper.Report" />
<%
    Integer iACSSystemKey;
    int nTotal;

    int nTotalLength;
    int nPeriodLength;
    int nMeasuresQuantity;

    nTotalLength = (int)(report.getFinalDate().getTime() - report.getInitialDate().getTime());
    nPeriodLength = nTotalLength / report.getPeriodsCount();

    nMeasuresQuantity = 0;

    for(nTotal = 0;nTotal < report.getFooter().getFieldsCount();nTotal++)
    {
        nMeasuresQuantity = nMeasuresQuantity + report.getFooter().getField(nTotal).getValuesCount();
    }
%>
<% 
    MeasurePoint oMeasurePoint;
    ReportPeriod oPeriod;
    ReportField oField;
    String sMeasurePointTag;
    String sMeasurePointsHeader;
    String sDateHeader;
    ReportPeriod oFooter;
    String sRowColor = "#E9E9E9";

    String sDate = new String("");

    int nMeasurePoints, nMeasurePoint;
    int nPeriods, nPeriod;
    int nFields, nField;

    SimpleDateFormat oDateFormat;
    NumberFormat oValueFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    String[] sCurvesColors = { "blue", "red", "green", "violet", "brown", "violet", "orange", "yellow", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray", "gray" };
    String sColor;

    oFooter = report.getFooter();
%>

<%
    int nTotalWidth = 1020;
    int nTotalHeight = 450;
    int nBorder = 5;

    int nLegendWidth = 140;
    int nLegendHeight = 300;
    int nLegendX = nTotalWidth - 2 * nBorder - nLegendWidth;
    int nLegendY = 40;

    int nGraphicWidth = 750;
    int nGraphicHeight = 300;
    int nGraphicX = 65;
    int nGraphicY = 40;

    double dMinimumLeftScale = 0;
    double dMaximumLeftScale = 60;
    int nLeftScaleDigits = 0;

    double dMinimumRightScale = 0;
    double dMaximumRightScale = 100;
    int nRightScaleDigits = 0;

    String sLeftScaleTitle = "";
    String sRightScaleTitle = "";
%>

<svg width="<%= nTotalWidth %>" height="<%= nTotalHeight %>" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<!-- External border of the graphic -->
<rect x="<%= nBorder %>" y="<%= nBorder %>" width="<%= (nTotalWidth - (2 * nBorder)) %>" height="<%= (nTotalHeight - (2 * nBorder)) %>" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />

<!-- Main title -->
<%
    oDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
%>
<text x="<%= (nGraphicX + nGraphicWidth / 2) %>" y="20" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px;" text-anchor="middle">R&#233;sultats du <%= oDateFormat.format(report.getInitialDate()) %> au <%= oDateFormat.format(report.getFinalDate()) %></text>

<!-- Legend -->
<rect x="<%= nLegendX %>" y="<%= nLegendY %>" width="<%= nLegendWidth %>" height="<%= nLegendHeight %>" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
<text x="<%= (nLegendX + nLegendWidth / 2)  %>" y="<%= (nLegendY + 15) %>" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px;" text-anchor="middle">L&#233;gende</text>

<%
    nMeasurePoints = report.getMeasurePointsCount();
    for(nMeasurePoint = 0;nMeasurePoint < nMeasurePoints;nMeasurePoint++)
    {
        sColor = sCurvesColors[nMeasurePoint];

        oMeasurePoint = report.getMeasurePoint(nMeasurePoint);
        if(oMeasurePoint.getUnit().length() > 0)
        {
            sMeasurePointTag = new String(oMeasurePoint.getName() + " (" + oMeasurePoint.getUnit() + ")");
        }
        else
        {
            sMeasurePointTag = oMeasurePoint.getName();
        }

        // Set scales from inputs unit
        if((sLeftScaleTitle.compareTo(oMeasurePoint.getUnit()) != 0) && (sRightScaleTitle.compareTo(oMeasurePoint.getUnit()) != 0))
        {
            if(sLeftScaleTitle.length() == 0)
            {
                sLeftScaleTitle = oMeasurePoint.getUnit();
                dMinimumLeftScale = oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMinimum();
                dMaximumLeftScale = oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMaximum();
                nLeftScaleDigits = oMeasurePoint.getValuePrecision();
            }
            else if(sRightScaleTitle.length() == 0)
            {
                sRightScaleTitle = oMeasurePoint.getUnit();
                dMinimumRightScale = oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMinimum();
                dMaximumRightScale = oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMaximum();
                nRightScaleDigits = oMeasurePoint.getValuePrecision();
            }
        }

        // Set scales minimum and maximum
        if(sLeftScaleTitle.compareTo(oMeasurePoint.getUnit()) == 0)
        {
            if(dMinimumLeftScale > oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMinimum())
            {
                dMinimumLeftScale = oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMinimum();
            }

            if(dMaximumLeftScale < oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMaximum())
            {
                dMaximumLeftScale = oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMaximum();
            }
        }
        else if(sRightScaleTitle.compareTo(oMeasurePoint.getUnit()) == 0)
        {
            if(dMinimumRightScale > oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMinimum())
            {
                dMinimumRightScale = oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMinimum();
            }

            if(dMaximumRightScale < oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMaximum())
            {
                dMaximumRightScale = oFooter.getField(nMeasurePoint).getMaximum();
            }
        }
%>
    <circle cx="<%= nLegendX + 10 %>" cy="<%= (nLegendY + 42 + nMeasurePoint * 15) %>" r="2" fill="<%= sColor %>" />
    <text x="<%= (nLegendX + 20)  %>" y="<%= (nLegendY + 45 + nMeasurePoint * 15) %>" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px;"><%= XML.encode(sMeasurePointTag) %></text>
<%
    }
%>

<!-- Graphic -->
<rect x="<%= nGraphicX  %>" y="<%= nGraphicY %>" width="<%= nGraphicWidth %>" height="<%= nGraphicHeight %>" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />

<!-- Left scale -->
<defs>
    <path id="leftScaleTitle" d="M <%= (nGraphicX - 40) %> <%= (nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight) %> L <%= (nGraphicX - 40) %> <%= nGraphicY %>" />
    <path id="rightScaleTitle" d="M <%= (nGraphicX + nGraphicWidth + 50) %> <%= (nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight) %> L <%= (nGraphicX + nGraphicWidth + 50) %> <%= nGraphicY %>" />
</defs>
<text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">
    <textPath xlink:href="#leftScaleTitle" text-anchor="middle" startOffset="50%"><%= XML.encode(sLeftScaleTitle) %></textPath>
</text>

<%
    int nY;
    int nLabel;
    int nLabels = 10;
    String sLabel;

    NumberFormat oLabelFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    oLabelFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(nLeftScaleDigits);
    oLabelFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(nLeftScaleDigits);

    for(nLabel = 0;nLabel <= nLabels;nLabel++)
    {
        nY = nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight - ((nGraphicHeight * nLabel) / nLabels);
        sLabel = oLabelFormat.format(dMinimumLeftScale + ((dMaximumLeftScale - dMinimumLeftScale) / nLabels) * nLabel);
%>
    <line x1="<%= (nGraphicX - 5) %>" y1="<%= nY %>" x2="<%= nGraphicX %>" y2="<%= nY %>" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-opacity="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
    <text x="<%= (nGraphicX - 10) %>" y="<%= nY + 3 %>" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px;" text-anchor="end"><%= sLabel %></text>
    <line x1="<%= nGraphicX %>" y1="<%= nY %>" x2="<%= (nGraphicX + nGraphicWidth) %>" y2="<%= nY %>" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-opacity="0.3" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke-dasharray="5, 5" />
<%
    }
%>

<!-- Right scale -->
<%
    if(!sRightScaleTitle.isEmpty())
    {
%>
    <text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#rightScaleTitle" text-anchor="middle" startOffset="50%"><%= XML.encode(sRightScaleTitle) %></textPath>
    </text>

<%
        nLabels = 10;

        oLabelFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(nRightScaleDigits);
        oLabelFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(nRightScaleDigits);

        for(nLabel = 0;nLabel <= nLabels;nLabel++)
        {
            nY = nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight - ((nGraphicHeight * nLabel) / nLabels);
            sLabel = oLabelFormat.format(dMinimumRightScale + ((dMaximumRightScale - dMinimumRightScale) / nLabels) * nLabel);
%>
        <line x1="<%= (nGraphicX + nGraphicWidth) %>" y1="<%= nY %>" x2="<%= (nGraphicX + nGraphicWidth + 5) %>" y2="<%= nY %>" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-opacity="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
        <text x="<%= (nGraphicX + nGraphicWidth + 35) %>" y="<%= nY + 3 %>" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px;" text-anchor="end"><%= sLabel %></text>
        <line x1="<%= nGraphicX %>" y1="<%= nY %>" x2="<%= (nGraphicX + nGraphicWidth) %>" y2="<%= nY %>" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-opacity="0.3" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke-dasharray="5, 5" />
<%
        }
    }
%>

<!-- Bottom scale -->
<text x="<%= (nGraphicX + nGraphicWidth / 2) %>" y="<%= (nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight + 80) %>" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;" text-anchor="middle">Temps</text>

<%
    int nX;
    String sLabelDate = "";
    String sLabelHour = "";
    String sLastLabelDate = "";

    nLabels = report.getPeriodsCount();

    int nLabelDelta = nLabels / 20;

    for(nLabel = 0;nLabel <= nLabels;nLabel+=nLabelDelta)
    {
        nX = nGraphicX + ((nLabel * nGraphicWidth) / nLabels);

        if(nLabel < report.getPeriodsCount())
        {
            oPeriod = report.getPeriod(nLabel);

            oDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            sLabelDate = oDateFormat.format(oPeriod.getInitialDate());

            oDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            sLabelHour = oDateFormat.format(oPeriod.getInitialDate());
%>
    <line x1="<%= nX %>" y1="<%= (nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight) %>" x2="<%= nX %>" y2="<%= (nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight + 5) %>" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-opacity="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
    <line x1="<%= nX %>" y1="<%= nGraphicY %>" x2="<%= nX %>" y2="<%= (nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight) %>" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-opacity="0.3" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke-dasharray="5, 5" />
<%
            if(sLastLabelDate.compareTo(sLabelDate) != 0)
            {
%>
    <defs>
        <path id="labelDate<%= nLabel %>" d="M <%= (nX - 4) %> <%= (nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight + 65) %> L <%= (nX - 4) %> 50" />
        <path id="labelHour<%= nLabel %>" d="M <%= (nX + 10) %> <%= (nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight + 65) %> L <%= (nX + 10) %> 50" />
    </defs>
    <text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#labelDate<%= nLabel %>"><%= sLabelDate %></textPath>
    </text>
    <text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#labelHour<%= nLabel %>"><%= sLabelHour %></textPath>
    </text>
<%
                sLastLabelDate = sLabelDate;
            }
            else
            {
%>
    <defs>
        <path id="labelHour<%= nLabel %>" d="M <%= (nX + 4) %> <%= (nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight + 65) %> L <%= (nX + 4) %> 50" />
    </defs>
    <text style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 9px;">
        <textPath xlink:href="#labelHour<%= nLabel %>"><%= sLabelHour %></textPath>
    </text>
<%
            }
        }
    }
%>

<!-- Curves -->
<%
    double dValue;

    boolean bLastPoint;
    int nLastX = 0;
    int nLastY = 0;
    double dMinimumScale = 0;
    double dMaximumScale = 0;

    nMeasurePoints = report.getMeasurePointsCount();
    for(nMeasurePoint = 0;nMeasurePoint < nMeasurePoints;nMeasurePoint++)
    {
        oMeasurePoint = report.getMeasurePoint(nMeasurePoint);

        bLastPoint = false;

        sColor = sCurvesColors[nMeasurePoint];

        if(sLeftScaleTitle.compareTo(oMeasurePoint.getUnit()) == 0)
        {
            dMinimumScale = dMinimumLeftScale;
            dMaximumScale = dMaximumLeftScale;
        }
        else if(sRightScaleTitle.compareTo(oMeasurePoint.getUnit()) == 0)
        {
            dMinimumScale = dMinimumRightScale;
            dMaximumScale = dMaximumRightScale;
        }
        else
        {
            dMinimumScale = 0;
            dMaximumScale = 1000;
        }

        nPeriods = report.getPeriodsCount();
        for(nPeriod = 0;nPeriod < nPeriods;nPeriod++)
        {
            oPeriod = report.getPeriod(nPeriod);

            oField = oPeriod.getField(nMeasurePoint);

            if(oField.getValuesCount() > 0)
            {
                nX = nGraphicX + ((nPeriod * nGraphicWidth) / nPeriods);

                dValue = oField.getAverage() - dMinimumScale;

                nY = nGraphicY + nGraphicHeight - (int)(nGraphicHeight * (dValue / (dMaximumScale - dMinimumScale)));

                if(bLastPoint)
                {
%>
    <line x1="<%= nLastX %>" y1="<%= nLastY %>" x2="<%= nX %>" y2="<%= nY %>" stroke="<%= sColor %>" />
<%
                }

                bLastPoint = true;
                nLastX = nX;
                nLastY = nY;

            }
            else
            {
                bLastPoint = false;
            }
        }
    }
%>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://svgfaces.org/tags-svg" prefix="s"%>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://svgfaces.org/tags-svg-animation" prefix="a"%>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://svgfaces.org/tags-svg-event" prefix="e"%>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
  <s:svg width="100%" height="100%">
      <!-- Rectangle to hide/show -->
      <c:forTokens items="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,13,14,15" delims="," var="s">
          <s:polygon x="120" y="-50" strokeWidth="1" stroke="black" fill="white" points="0,0 50,0 60,10 60,20 0,20" id="text${s}" />
      </c:forTokens>

      <!-- hide-button -->
      <s:rect x="10" y="180" id="hide" width="100" height="20" fill="red">
          <e:onclick>
              <c:forTokens items="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,13,14,15" delims="," var="s">
                  <a:move path="M0 ${s*30+100} L 0 0" id="text${s}" dur="0.4"/>

                  <a:hide id="text${s}" delay="0.4" />
              </c:forTokens>
          </e:onclick>
      </s:rect>
      <s:text x="15" text="Hide" y="195"/>

      <!-- show-button -->
      <s:rect x="10" y="200" width="100" height="20" fill="green" id="show">
          <e:onclick>

              <c:forTokens items="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,13,14,15" delims="," var="s">
                  <a:display id="text${s}" />
                  <a:move path="M0 0 L 00 ${s*30+100}" id="text${s}" dur="0.4"/>
              </c:forTokens>

          </e:onclick>
      </s:rect>
      <s:text x="15" text="Show" y="215"/>
  </s:svg>
```

Comment: Where did you get the tag library from?

Comment: I notice that it is offline. I'm trying to add svg code inside a .tag file the proper way. I really don't need svg surfaces tho. I just though of peeking at it.